# Окей или О'кей?

Tags: заимствования, апостроф

Как писать более правильно американское выражение Okay: "Окей" или "О'кей", тем более голосом мы не отделяем первую букву "О"? Апостроф в русском языке используется в основном в случае иностранных имён, фамилий и названий (как правило, франкоязычных) и старомодном написании слов без "Ъ" типа "под'езд", а как в **этом** случае? Сеть магазинов "О'Кей" тут, конечно, не показатель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Окей" или
>   "О'кей"?

[**Правильны оба варианта:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE*%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, такой рекомендации кто-нибудь придерживается? Обычно пишут "ок". Слава, а вам вы видели подобные написания на практике?

Comment: "ок" - это в Интернете для сокращения. Меня же интересует исключительно в художественной литературе, прямая речь, особенно если действующие лица - американцы (но это непринципиально)...

Comment: Не один ли кей...